# Is this generalization of the Hopf map for quadratic field extensions surjective?

Tags: nt.number-theory, matrices, fields, hopf-fibration

Let $k$ be a field, and let $L$ be a quadratic extension of $k$. Denote by $\sigma$ the non-trivial element of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/k)$. Let $M_2(L)$ be the vector space over $L$ of two-by-two matrices with entries in $L$. Let
$$H^0_2(L/k) = \bigl\{ y \in L(2); \sigma(y)^T = y \text{ and } \operatorname{tr}(y) = 0 \bigr\}.$$ 
and define the map $j: L^2 \to L^2$ by
$$j \begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -\sigma(v) \\ \sigma(u) \end{pmatrix}.$$ We also let $(-,-): L^2 \times L^2 \to L$ be defined by
$$(\mathbf{u_1},\mathbf{u_2}) = u_1 \sigma(u_2) + v_1 \sigma(v_2)$$
where $\mathbf{u_i} = (u_i,v_i)^T$, for $i=1,2$.
Define
$$M^j_2(L) = \{x \in M_2(L); x j = j x \bigr\}.$$
We now define the map:

$$h: M^j_2(L) \to H^0_2(L/k),\qquad h(x) = \sigma(x)^T 
\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\\\end{pmatrix}x.$$

While it is clear that the image of $h$ lies in $H_2(L/k)$, it remains to check that $\operatorname{tr}(h(x)) = 0$, for any $x \in M^j_2(L)$. Let $x \in M^j_2(L)$. We know that
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{tr}(h(x)) &= \operatorname{tr}\left(x\sigma(x)^T \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\\\end{pmatrix}\right) \\
&= (x\sigma(x)^T e_1, e_1)-(x\sigma(x)^T e_2, e_2) \\
&= (x\sigma(x)^T e_1, e_1)-(x\sigma(x)^T je_1, je_1) \\
&= (\sigma(x)^T e_1, \sigma(x)^Te_1)-(\sigma(x)^T je_1, \sigma(x)^T je_1) \\
&= (\sigma(x)^T e_1, \sigma(x)^Te_1)-(j\sigma(x)^T e_1, j\sigma(x)^Te_1) \\
&= (\sigma(x)^T e_1, \sigma(x)^Te_1)-\sigma(\sigma(x)^T e_1, \sigma(x)^Te_1) \\
&= 0 .\end{align}$$

**Question 1**: for which pairs $(k,L)$ is the corresponding map $h$ surjective? It is surjective if $k=\mathbb{R}$ and $L=\mathbb{C}$, since $h$ is essentially the Hopf map in this case. What about in general?

**Question 2**: what can be said about the fibers of $h$?

**Edit 1:** I realized that the target space should be the space of hermitian *tracefree* matrices, otherwise the statement would not even be true for $k=\mathbb{R}$ and $L=\mathbb{C}$. This led me to modify my original post accordingly, and introduce the "quaternionic structure" $j$ on $L^2$, and also restrict the domain to the "real slice" of $M_2(L)$ which is $j$-equivariant.

**Edit 2:** I further assume that $\operatorname{char}(k) \neq 2$, otherwise, the corresponding generalized Hopf map is not surjective for trivial reasons, by working out the formula for the generalized Hopf map explicitly (a small calculation).

**Edit 3:** for $h$ to be surjective for some pair $(k,L)$, necessary and sufficient conditions are:

condition 1: for all $z \in k$ and all $\zeta \in L$, $z^2+N(\zeta)$ is a square in $k$.

condition 2: for all $z \in k$ and all $\zeta \in L$, the system
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rl} 4t^2 + 4zt - N(\zeta) &= 0 \\
               N(v) &= \pm t \end{array} \right.$$ 
has at least one non-zero solution $v \in L$, for at least one possible choice of sign in the second equation.

I don't expect these conditions to hold for any pair $(k,L)$. I have obtained these conditions roughly by eliminating one of the two variables with values in $L$ which describe an element $x \in M^j_2(L)$.

**Edit 4:** We can replace condition 2 in edit 3 by an easier to check condition, in practice, which I will denote by condition 2'. For $h$ to be surjective for some pair $(k,L)$, necessary and sufficient conditions are:

condition 1: for all $z \in k$ and all $\zeta \in L$, $z^2+N(\zeta)$ is a square in $k$.

condition 2': for all $z \in k$, either $z=N(v)$ or $-z=N(v)$ for some $v \in L$.

**Edit 5:** The conditions 1 and 2' in Edit 4 are equivalent to the following 3 conditions. For $h$ to be surjective for some pair $(k,L)$, necessary and sufficient conditions are:

condition A: $\operatorname{Im}(N) = \{ z^2; z\in k \}$

condition B: for any $z \in k$, either $z$ or $-z$ is a square in $k$.

condition C: for any $z_1,z_2 \in k$, the element $z_1^2+z_2^2$ is a square in $k$, i.e. $k$ is a Pythagorean field.

We see that condition C cannot be satisfied if for instance $k = \mathbb{F}_p$, with $p$ an odd prime, since it implies that any element in $k$ is a square, which is a contradiction (since exactly half the elements in $\mathbb{F}^\times_p$ are squares. Similarly, one gets a contradiction if $k$ is a finite field of characteristic $p$, with $p$ an odd prime, since by condition B and the fact that $k$ is finite, we deduce that $-1$ is a non-square in $k$. But condition C implies that $-1$ is a square in $k$, so we get a contradiction. Hence, for the generalized Hopf map $h$ to be surjective, $k$ must be infinite.

Similarly, since number fields are not pythagorean, we deduce that if $k$ is a number field, then the corresponding Hopf map $h$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

By taking $P$ to be the set of squares in $k$, I can show that my conditions in Edit 5 imply that $P$ is a prepositive cone on $k$, so that $k$ is an ordered Euclidean field. The quadratic extension $L$ is then isomorphic to $k(\sqrt{-d})$ where $d \in k$, and $d>0$. Conversely, if $k$ is an ordered Euclidean field and $L = k(\sqrt{-d})$, where $d \in k$ and $d>0$, conditions A, B and C in Edit 5 are easily seen to hold.

So we have proved that the generalized Hopf map associated to a pair $(k,L)$, where $k$ is a field and $L$ is a quadratic extension, is surjective iff $k$ is an ordered Euclidean field and $L = k(\sqrt{-d})$, where $d \in k$ and $d>0$.

In particular, we get for instance that the generalized Hopf map is surjective if $k$ is the constructible field and $L = k(i)$.